# Lexical or Preprocessor issue in xcode while building flutter app

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I am trying to build ios app from flutter I have the android part done and dusted. I am new to ios and facing problem while building ios app. I have used

- google_maps_flutter: ^0.0.3+3
- flutter_youtube
- firebase_messaging

[image: flutter app ios build xcode]

build log[image: xcode build log]

Comment: can you show the build log ?

Comment: I have added in the question...

Comment: do you find a solution for this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an issue with the iOS build of the project. Usually, you wouldn't need to do any modifications on the iOS build. You can try regenerating the iOS build by deleting the `/ios` folder and generating a new one by running `flutter create --platforms=ios` on the terminal.